# How to write to a file using comma delimiter and no double quote in string?

Tags: vba

I would like to print a range of date into .txt file with some special header so that a special software called Prophet could recognize.

```
Sub Export_TEST()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim prophetheader As String
Dim prophetlineheader As String
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & "test" & ".txt"
Set rng = Selection

prophetheader = "!1"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Print #1, rng.Columns.Count - 1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Print #1, cellValue
        ElseIf i = 1 And j = 1 Then
            Print #1, prophetheader, cellValue,
        ElseIf j = 1 Then
            Print #1, "*", cellValue,
        Else
            Print #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Close #1

End Sub
```

The code is quite straight forward, just add * in the front of each line and add !1 in the column header. But I encounter the issue that the output file has been delimited using comma and no double quotation in the string. And I am in the dilemma that if I use write function, it will use comma as delimiter, but has double quotation on string and if I use Print, space as delimiter and no double quote on string.

Is there a way to print the file using comma delimiter and no double quote on string?

Below is the dummy data selection.

SPCODE NAME

1      JS

And the output should be

21

!1,SPCODE,NAME

*,1,JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of writing each single row to the text file you just write each line in total like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export_TEST()
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim prophetheader As String
    Dim prophetlineheader As String
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test" & ".txt"
    Set rng = Selection

    prophetheader = "!1"
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, rng.Columns.Count - 1

    Dim line As String
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        line = ""
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                line = line & cellValue & ","
            ElseIf i = 1 And j = 1 Then
                line = line & prophetheader & cellValue & ","
            ElseIf j = 1 Then
                line = line & "*" & cellValue & ","
            Else
                line = line & cellValue & ","
            End If
        Next j
        line = Left(line, Len(line) - 1)
        Print #1, line
    Next i
    Close #1

End Sub
```